# Can't unmount React component, returning false from parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to perform authorization on a child component against certain permissions. I'm using `ref` callback to get access to the Node, wherein I can check permissions. Depending on these permissions, I would like to unmount the component.

Within the callback, I'm trying to use `ReactDOM.findDOMNode()` and then `ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode()` to remove it. The latter keeps returning false, although `findDomNode` appears to properly be selecting the DOM element.

```
class Auth extends React.Component {

    ...

    checkPermissions(component) {
        const domNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(component); // => <p>...</p>

        if (domNode) {
            let wasUnmounted = ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(domNode);
            console.log('was unmounted', wasUnmounted); // => false
        }
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.authorized &&
                    <Component ref={(c) => this.checkPermissions(c)} {...this.props} />
                }
            </div>
        )
    }

    ...
```

*How can I use `ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode()` to effectively remove my component?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll want to mount your node just to check permissions and then unmount it. You should check permissions *before* you render. Not only is it more secure, but it's also simpler.

If the user is authorized, you render the component. If the user is not authorized, you render something else.

So something kind of like this:

```js
render() {
  if (!this.state.authorized) {
    return <PleaseLogIn />;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Component {...this.props} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you find yourself manipulating the DOM manually, take a step back and make sure there's not a more "Reacty" way to do it.

Update:

If you want a wrapper component that you can put around things that should or shouldn't render its children based on permissions maybe you do something like this:

```js
// state.userPermissions = ['permission1', 'permission1', 'betaTolerant'];

const AuthWrapper = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    userPermissions: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    requiredPermissions: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    children: React.PropTypes.node.isRequired
  },

  isAllowed() {
    const { userPermissions, requiredPermissions } = this.props;
    return requiredPermissions.some((requiredPermission) => {
      return userPermissions.some((userPermission) => {
        // If this ever returns true, isAllowed will return true
        // Meaning: If any of the requiredPermissions match
        // any of the userPermissions
        return requiredPermission === userPermission;
      });
    });
  },

  render {
    if(!this.isAllowed()) return null;
    return this.props.children;
  };
});

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  // Only this auth component has access to state
  return {
    userPermissions: state.userPermissions
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  null
)(AuthWrapper);
```

Now you can use this wrapper like:

```js
// Inside some component
render {
  return (
    <MyApp>
      <NormalFeature />
      <AuthWrapper requiredPermissions=['secretFeature', 'betaTolerant']>
        <SecretFeature />
      </AuthWrapper>
    </MyApp>
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm happy to adopt a more "Reacty" approach, but thus far I haven't been able to find one. I want to set permissions *at the component level*, and then render the component depending on those permissions (whether or not they match the permissions specified in the data store). I don't want to incorporate any more logic besides just _the permissions_ in the component. Do you know of a way to access child component methods from a parent component without first rendering the DOM node?

Comment: What kind of permissions does a component need? Can you pass down those permissions from parent components?

Comment: I want a single, all-encompassing authorization component that determines whether or not the child component renders. I have a long list of permissions that are specific to individual components. The permissions are just string values.

I'm looking for a solution that allows me to specify these permissions inside of the component, and then use the parent, Auth, component to check those against the permissions in the data store.

Comment: How about a wrapper component that receives an array of permissions and if one of those permissions matches the "allowed" permission, it renders the child component. like `<AuthWrapper permissions=[{beta: true}, {someFeature: false}] /><Child /></AuthWrapper>`.

Comment: Yes, that's the sort of thing I would like to do, but seems like it would still require that I have access to methods inside of the child component to determine which permissions are allowed.

Comment: Are the permissions stored on some sort of `permissions` object on a `userObject` of some kind? Presumably you're auth'ing the user and what you get back is a list of her permissions?

Comment: Yes, I'm using a Redux store to house a list of the user's permissions. Her permissions would then, presumably, be checked against the component's "required" permissions. The component would then render accordingly.

Comment: Check out my updated answer. I haven't tested it but hopefully the concept makes sense.

Comment: It makes sense, thank you. I do wish there was a way to specify permissions at the component level instead of a wrapper, but this certainly seems like a solution to work with.

Comment: You could simply `connect` any component you want to your state and check permissions that way. But you'll have to do that over and over again and it maybe doesn't make sense for a component itself to check permissions because it sort of breaks its re-usability.

Comment: Looking more like using static methods are the way to go. They allow parent components to call them before rendering.